# Saving an Image on Data Base

Tags: java, sql, image

Basically I have to save an image I put on a JLabel on my DB(I have a BLOB var there)

`JLabel LImg = new JLabel();
 ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("**filepath**");
 LImg.setIcon(img);
 stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO CLIENT(ID, IMAGE) VALUES (1,"+LImg.getIcon()+")");`

After running a few tests, I found out the getIcon method returns the file path, which explains this error

> GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
>   SQL error code = -104
>   Token unknown - line 1, column 132
>
> > :

Please, be especific on your answer(I'm new on JAVA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot paste the image itself into a SQL statement. You need to use a parameterized prepared statement, and set the value being inserted as a byte array:

```
BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage)LImg.getImage();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi, type, baos);
byte[] dataToWrite = baos.toByteArray();
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CLIENT(ID, IMAGE) VALUES (1,?)");
stmt.setBlob(1, dataToWrite);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```